# Prevent OnServerClick in OnClick?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onclick, postback, dom-events

I'm using ASP.NET and I have a link which has both onclick and onserverclick.  Both are important, but I want the onclick to prevent the onserverclick running if at all possible.

Here is the item I'm playing with at the moment:

```
    <ul class="clickables">
        <asp:Repeater ID="MenuRepeater" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li class=" <%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["CSSClass"]%>" 
                    style="background-color: <%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["BackgroundColour"]%>">
                    <a id="A1" 
                        runat="server" 
                        onserverclick="LinkClick"
                        onclick=<%# "return javascript:LinkClick('" + ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Postback"] + "')" %>
                        customid='<%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["UniqueID"]%>'
                        href='<%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["PageFile"]%>'>
                    </a>
                    <%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["DisplayName"]%>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ul>
```

Here's the JS I'm expecting to stop the postback:

```
function LinkClick(parameters) {
    if (parameters[0] == "False") {
        return false;
    }
```

Am I missing something?  Is this even possible?  I know that I can prevent a normal postback by returning false in onclick, but can I stop the onserverclick?

***UPDATE***
After debugging a little more (been away from webdev for a while...), the JS function isn't firing...

***UPDATE 2***

Here is the full rendered page source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="iphone.css" />

<link href="MenuStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-core-1.4.5-full-nocompat-yc.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Main.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="zxCYbgjQBAQXVsCg6EwWqRNbeqa/5PzOIgwdhVB5mEasbEk06ik+VT9njAhsM8vF0ymfwdsNmbuX2R7iMJjdpqLMAVABvva4eorpK2PdajpD+g2RzFXI5SEEG9VjwQUXf3kKgb0KnPjWGYQdgZHGDQ==" />
</div>
    <div>
        <div class="button">Back</div>
        <div class="button-bold">+</div>
        <h1>AAR</h1>
        <h2 id="lblQuestion">Please wait for a question...</h2>
        <ul class="clickables">


                    <li class=" arrow" 
                        style="background-color: White">
                        <a id="MenuRepeater_A1_0" onclick="return&#32;LinkClick(&#39;True&#39;)" customid="80f03602-cb67-4d46-99ea-4200459e6a48" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;MenuRepeater$ctl01$A1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
                        </a>
                        Question 1
                    </li>

                    <li class=" " 
                        style="background-color: LightGray">
                        <a id="MenuRepeater_A1_1" onclick="return&#32;LinkClick(&#39;False&#39;)" customid="91f76613-ecaa-47df-a5d6-5a921935b1f9" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;MenuRepeater$ctl02$A1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
                        </a>
                        Question 2
                    </li>


        </ul>
        <ul class="clickables">

        </ul>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        $$('.clickables').each(function(clickable) {
            var list = clickable.getElements('li');

            list.addEvent('click', function() {
                var link = this.getElement('a');
                if(this.getFirst('a')) {
                    window.location = link;
                }
            });
        });

        function LinkClick(parameters) {
            if (parameters[0] == "False") {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

***Edit 3***

Even when I do:

```
onclick='return LinkClick(False)'
```

OR

```
onclick="return LinkClick(False)"
```

I still get:

```
onclick="return&#32;LinkClick(&#39;True&#39;)"
```

***Edit 4***

Here is the current rendered source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="iphone.css" />

<link href="MenuStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-core-1.4.5-full-nocompat-yc.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Main.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="vi/Uef51SWAjwpFRuN3fwE5Y2FDB84KMHL6HjRIbWSKMEsSrg2RiGbteExTKFCbKhGe16A7xsn6DzMULMalMxqrg2yi9wkWZb0w2ifgCG6mmU0fH3V6zELQeACrtHDQ+4YlxeZ8k7HfGC592ammq3g==" />
</div>
    <div>
        <div class="button">Back</div>
        <div class="button-bold">+</div>
        <h1>AAR</h1>
        <h2 id="lblQuestion">Please wait for the question...</h2>
        <ul class="clickables">


                    <li class=" arrow" 
                        style="background-color: White">
                        <a id="MenuRepeater_A1_0" onclick="return LinkClick(True);" customid="b88d214b-0d1c-4986-821e-c1650ffbdbfd" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;MenuRepeater$ctl01$A1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
                        </a>
                        Question 1
                    </li>

                    <li class=" " 
                        style="background-color: LightGray">
                        <a id="MenuRepeater_A1_1" onclick="return LinkClick(False);" customid="d566775f-4bee-4069-adb0-27e8cf8057d9" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;MenuRepeater$ctl02$A1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
                        </a>
                        Question 2
                    </li>


        </ul>
        <ul class="clickables">



        </ul>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        $$('.clickables').each(function(clickable) {
            var list = clickable.getElements('li');

            list.addEvent('click', function() {
                var link = this.getElement('a');
                if(this.getFirst('a')) {
                    window.location = link;
                }
            });
        });

        function LinkClick(parameters) {
            if (parameters[0] == "False") {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

***Update 5***

So if I leave the method and just return true/false it should stop the postback?  This doesn't work (more rendered source).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="iphone.css" />

<link href="MenuStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-core-1.4.5-full-nocompat-yc.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <script>
        function LinkClick(parameters) {
            if (parameters[0] == "False") {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>
    <form method="post" action="Main.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="PiZp7nhFhCoiWV3slT5szv5Z5GAkeDWYHj7QpAPmnwSoKxWg6Zm9HTQGkZXS2Osddx6KwS0eGu/ZMaLjgxVBm1U+Eszzf/OjmAbB78jPAeSwW8GwXRUUp984a7cPZc9cYajKHkhBVtuuALV6HSsT3oRzEPlziohjgWGiV8HFAEOd1CWTj+RAC3B/mWcmrFcexzpR1XhQgnV5LQC7GplUB9Y2E/rb8MFQHfYsRxG5GjWJ5zqe51FhwstLL/dbSklaBkRlFHyFyZNUeA74My6AHCOAWbUjZ42sVcMjaSVnM1zZsxQtSG8+UdbshaLZ9Gz5SOB0Vq4fS8J+TrUlswsSLqQ77Q+m2ouZG+jhPf7jKC59KvIYGlKHkgYVqCvhqhkIG91xg7k9M3f5KAf0yOB6yaesVxnWBCC+UQWcKRePIV9tq2eE8C+8F+rLCPJ6RXgUzpC+DvVmlQMHzmiXWLehtymb2HRX4O/2RUJxLDlVP/8=" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="aQDXp34k4YJiEBt3URBFL0do/c8NXsEmuBtFz8JLRhtXerYXPFYRZmyXIpCef68aO7itJ4EUwQ9eXl2KkxDndTmS4149nNN8BX3AoFLDgB0b4w6cNsn3nzoZ3ENnU4vExyeHdXVJyyVwmZruhoQ7GA==" />
</div>
    <div>
        <div class="button">Back</div>
        <div class="button-bold">+</div>
        <h1>AAR</h1>
        <h2 id="lblQuestion">Please wait for a question...</h2>
        <ul class="clickables">


                    <li class=" arrow"
                        style="background-color: White">
                        <a id="MenuRepeater_A1_0" onclick="return true;" customid="b88d214b-0d1c-4986-821e-c1650ffbdbfd" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;MenuRepeater$ctl01$A1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"></a>
                        Question 1
                    </li>

                    <li class=" "
                        style="background-color: LightGray">
                        <a id="MenuRepeater_A1_1" onclick="return false;" customid="d566775f-4bee-4069-adb0-27e8cf8057d9" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;MenuRepeater$ctl02$A1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"></a>
                        Question 2
                    </li>


        </ul>
        <ul class="clickables">

        </ul>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        $$('.clickables').each(function (clickable) {
            var list = clickable.getElements('li');

            list.addEvent('click', function () {
                var link = this.getElement('a');
                if (this.getFirst('a')) {
                    window.location = link;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How that <li> element looks rendered in browser?

Comment: I render it with CSS to be a menu... I've updated my code with a little extra around the LI item.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: @jrummell - Nope, none at all...

Comment: Its easy to find the problem if you see the source of the page, the html and javascript rendered.

Comment: @Aristos - I added the full rendered source...

Comment: I'm not sure. It's html encoding your attribute values for some reason.

Comment: &32; is a space and &39; is ", you didn't wrap the <%# ... %> with the single quote as you did for the other properties..

Comment: I can't wrap that server tag in quotes, I end up with a "not well formed" error...

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano - It really didn't like apostrophes around onlick... More errors than you could shake a stick at!

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano "The server tag is not well formed." :(  No specific line/char reference...

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano - Also did you see my edit about calling the function without serverside stuff?  IT's still putting crap in the source..

Comment: sorry, i deleted the last comments cause i read the other answer **after** posting them... last thing, using <%= ... %> instead of <%# ... %>?

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano, no luck.. and last thing?  Damn... I think I need the scooby crew on this one...

Comment: have to go to sleep (here in italy are 23:17) but the very last thing, why not try to use the <asp:hyperlink/> instead of <a>? good luck with the unsolved mistery

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano - What makes you think Hyperlink would work better?  and it's 22:22 here, so I'll play some more.  I'm at the point where I can get "onclick="return&#32;LinkClick(True);"", I just need to get rid of that last "&#32;", I even tried string.format and it didn't help... something about sending the text to the server is encoding it...

Comment: I can not reproduce this code, for some reason you have set a custom html encode on the control fields that make this htmlEncode.

Comment: @Aristos it was .net xss stuff (see my answer).  If you have a better solution please post it, I don't want others turning off xss when they shouldn't (mine is a private site with only lan access)

Comment: @Vijay You do not turn it off, you just let the build in to Encode. I think that this is a bug of this encoder. The Net 4.0 have an inside encoder, but you can change it by this line. If you remove this encoder, then the inisde encoder is still encode this lines. (but with out this bug)

Comment: @Aristos - Can you explain what you mean?  You are saying it's build in to Encode now, how do I turn that off?

Comment: @Vijay The inside encode is not turn off... but is not affect the code, I make a test on a code like yours and its work. Also read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912401/control-attributes-render-encoded-on-dot-net-4-how-to-disable-the-encoding

Comment: @Aristos, I forgot the point of this question I got diverted by the error.  Now (Edit 4) the rendered source is correct but I don't hit my Javascript method "LinkClick" - Do you know why?

Comment: Because the function is after the call. You must move the function before the line that you call it. And the `True` must be `true` and the `False` must be `false` (or make them text)

Comment: @Aristos - Thanks for your help, the function wasn't being run, but I moved the method and changed the type to false/true and it didn't work.  I then tried (update 5) to just return true/false and returning false doesn't stop the postback...

Comment: I'm trying to top the onserverclick method running in JS, I set "Onclick="return false"" and it doesn't stop it...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see that `parameters[0] == "False"`? Could be a string comparison issue? Or it could be that your text is actually outside of the link tag:

```
<a id="A1" 
    runat="server" 
    onserverclick="LinkClick"
    onclick=<%# "return javascript:LinkClick('" + ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Postback"] + "')" %>
    customid='<%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["UniqueID"]%>'
    href='<%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["PageFile"]%>'>
</a>
<%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["DisplayName"]%>
```

should probably be:

```
<a id="A1" 
    runat="server" 
    onserverclick="LinkClick"
    onclick=<%# "return javascript:LinkClick('" + ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Postback"] + "')" %>
    customid='<%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["UniqueID"]%>'
    href='<%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["PageFile"]%>'>
    <%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["DisplayName"]%>
</a>
```

Comment: I've updated my question with a bit more detail.  The DisplayName tag is meant to be where it is, so that it's rendered as part of the li text rather than the a text.

Comment: But, what is giving the `a` tag any dimension?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.  I've just updated my question again, the issue appears to be that the JS isn't firing... I must have something wrong in there...

Comment: Is the server-side click firing? (I.e. Is the page posting-back?) What I mean by 'dimension' is that with nothing inside the `a` tag it has no width or height and therefore cannot be clicked.

Comment: Try putting the text inside the `a` tag just to see if it works.

Comment: It can be clicked, the clicking definitely works... The page is posting back... I'm using mootools 

        $$('.clickables').each(function(clickable) {
            var list = clickable.getElements('li');

            list.addEvent('click', function() {
                var link = this.getElement('a');
                if(this.getFirst('a')) {
                    window.location = link;
                }
            });
        });


-- Also, putting the text in the a tag didn't help.

Comment: When I view source on that I see this: `onclick=return&#32;LinkClick(&#39;True&#39;)` That's not gonna work.

Comment: I get that, but how do I fix it?  I have no idea why the spaces are being encoded... The value on the server is "True" (I set it statically right now).

Answer (score 0):

You should not do `onclick=<%# .... %>`, because that automatically encodes output.

It should be something like:

```
<a onclick="javascript:return LinkClick('<%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Postback"] %>')" href="something"></a>
```

Your output `return&#32;LinkClick(&#39;True&#39;)` is not even javascript call. That's why you don't see any error.

There is usefull link about asp.net inline expressions:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112

Comment: Hi, your html is invalid (The server tag is not well formed.)

Comment: Yes, this is simple example, but explains the problem. And that's wrapping complete attribute value with <%# ... %>. I think it's clear.

Comment: @nNenad - I understand what you are saying, but as far as I know there is no possible way to do it your way.  I wrapped the whole thing in a tag because I had to.  If I don't I get the tag error (above).

Comment: Ups, fixed typo. Doesn't work, hmm. Not sure how you set example. In worst case you can use <%= "text" + data + "more text" %>, but it that case you have to make sure that you Html encoded data properly. There is good link about usage of inline expressions, I just added it to the post.

Comment: Even just with a direct call I get the html entity codes... That's what's crazy.  Thanks for the link, I'll read up and see if it helps at all, but with a regular call not working I'm not sure what to do!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all so much for your help.  The issue was .NET's XSS stuff (built in, automagically screwing with you via the config file..)

Once I removed this line it worked, I guess the way I'm getting my server variable into the JS makes my site think it's being attacked...  It's going to be a private site anyway, so XSS is being turned off.  If anyone can find a better solution (safer) then please post and I'll try it out...

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="4.5" targetFramework="4.5" encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

^^ Remove that line from Web.config (at your own peril)...

Comment: glad to see you catch the problem!
in my previous comment i was talking about change the <a> tag with the <asp:hyperlink> 'cause i've digged all the forums i know for a similar issue and there was no sample with <a> tag so i supposed there could be some related issue... i was terribly wrong so please accept my apologize

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano - No need to apologize, you sat here for aaaaage trying to help me, that's amazing!  Thanks you so much for your help, if you guys hadn't all stuck around and kept asking questions and telling me to try things I'd have never found the issue.  I'd stil like to find a better way than disabling XSS, although it works for me, if I mark it as the answer someone might just do it without thinking about the consequences! :S  Thanks again!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, then suppressing the onserverclick because of something that happended in the onclick event is quite simple:

```
<span class="psw">Forgot <a href="" runat="server" onclick="return checkForRequiredEmailAddress();" onserverclick="ForgotPassword">password?</a></span>
```

This is an actual forgot password link on one of my pages.  The code behind ForgotPassword() method specified in the onserverclick event is never triggered unless a valid email address is present.

The 'checkForRequiredEmailAddress' method checks for its existence, structure and correctness and then returns true or false depending on the outcome of the checks.

I know your question says that you tried this, but it is definitely working for me so I can only assume it is something silly.  Maybe the missing semi-colon in the click event makes a difference.