# ASP.NET 4.5.x Attributes.Add Double and Single Quote issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013

I'm using the Attributes.Add to inject some tags into my HTML. The tags get injected but in a weird way

What I get is this

```
data-groups="&#39;[&quot;ALL&quot;,&quot;NAV&quot;,&quot;DOC&quot;]&#39;"
```

what I want is this

```
data-groups='["ALL","NAV","DOC"]'
```

Any ideas ?

The code that does the work is this

```
string sFilter = "ALL,NAV,DOC";

sFilter = string.Format(@"'[|{0}|]'", sFilter.Replace(",","|,|"));

sFilter = sFilter.Replace("|", @"""");
sFilter = sFilter.Replace("'", "\'");

oControl.Attributes.Add("data-groups", sFilter);
```

I've ready something about an encoding bug with 4.0 and above. Any suggestions how I can fix this ?

Comment: How are you setting up everything to get what you're getting?

Comment: I dont know what you mean, can you clarify please

Comment: same question 5 years ago... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912401/control-attributes-render-encoded-on-dot-net-4-how-to-disable-the-encoding

Comment: Sorry :) I have included now

Comment: @Aristos Sorry that doesn't work, that example is against Net 4.0 and I am using Net 4.5.x

Comment: @djack109 The version have nothing to do, I am afraid that asp.net did not let you do what you try ! only with custom encoding or if you render your control by your self... sorry no solution with any option on control

Comment: @Aristos. Thanks. I was beginning to come to the same conclusion.