# How can I add attributes to limit letters for a text field on ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I 'd like to limit letters to be entered for a text field on my web page(ASP.NET4.6) though, it doesn't work this code. Numeric letters are only needed to be entered for this field!
Could you tell me why??

The following HTML is generating.

```
onkeyPress="javascript: if (((event.keyCode &lt; 48) || (event.keyCode > 57)) &amp;&amp; (event.keyCode != 45) &amp;&amp; (event.keyCode!=46)){window.event.returnValue = false;}"
```

The line above is generated from this VB.NET.

```
TNt1.Attributes("onkeyPress") = "javascript: if (((event.keyCode < 48) || (event.keyCode > 57)) && (event.keyCode != 45) && (event.keyCode!=46)){window.event.returnValue = false;}"
```

Comment: do you see that `&lt;` ? for security reasons the text on the attribute is encoding. If I remember well is impossible to not encode it. So maybe create a javascript function to call. See my question 10 years ago how to not encode them -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912401/control-attributes-render-encoded-on-dot-net-4-how-to-disable-the-encoding

Comment: Aristos, Thank you for advising it! After I changed this into a function, then called and I could finally get succeed.I really appreciate it!

Comment: So I make it answer, to accept it, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript is break because by default the attribute set is encoding by asp.net to avoid page break, or other possible attacks.

So its **not possible to avoid encoding the attribute ***, and its better to add your code inside a javascript function and avoid the special characters to break the javascript code.

reference 
[Control Attributes render Encoded on dot net 4 - how to disable the encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912401/control-attributes-render-encoded-on-dot-net-4-how-to-disable-the-encoding)

(*) at least not easy with just a flag or a simple code.

Answer (score 0):

In html you can use the number attribute for an input, like here:
[w3schools input number](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number)

Answer (score 0):

The MaxLength property should do it.

```
<asp:TextBox  ID="txt1" MaxLength="5" runat="server" />
```